# Is there an "if" function in Excel for auto-filling a user ID number based on a separate user ID number that's already been found?

Tags: excel, dataframe, excel-formula, autocomplete, autofill

I am trying to auto-fill a person's user ID number based on repeat information in the table. I have an excel sheet with people that have two user ID #'s so I would like to auto-fill the second number based on the first. i.e. I have 3 columns. Column 1 = name, column 2 = user ID #1 and column 3 = user ID #2. So if Gerald = 3 and 5, how do I get excel to auto-fill the user ID #2 as 5 every time column 2 = 3. It's the same data repeated over and over. As in I have multiple Gerald entries and I want it to auto-fill everytime he comes up based on his first user ID#. It's all in the same sheet so I don't have to switch tabs or anything.

I've tried going through "if" functions but I don't know how to make the right formula.